# "Drawer" panel keeps showing up on refresh

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I just upgraded my chrome version to 49.0.2623.87, and now the "drawer" panel that contains the console keeps showing up when I refresh (F5) my page with the dev-tools opened.

Apparently there was a fix in the "emulator" panel but it seems that the checkbox this fix was using does not exist anymore.

Is anyone having the same problem and managed to fixed it ?

Comment: It is happening when I try to edit the value of a property in the Style box. I can type one character before it switches to a console window!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Got it.
With Dev Tools open hit F1 to open the settings.
Uncheck 'Enable CSS source maps'
Close the Settings box.

This has worked for my problem with the console opening all the time - I've just restested and this is the only option you need to change. I am sure it will fix your issue as well as it is linked strongly with mine.

Comment: Wow! This actually worked, except that I had to also disable JavaScript source maps. Pretty strange but thanks a lot

Comment: What if I'm using CSS source maps and Javascript source maps? Has anyone found a solution for that? I'll sure appreciate it... this drawer issue drives me nuts. It appeared with the latest update for Chrome.

Comment: This seems more like a bug than an actual fix, but it does the trick.

Comment: awesome! i have disabled "Enable JavaScript source maps" too to fix it.

Comment: This answer is outdated and doesn't work any more. Console still pops open even with both source map options unchecked. This is consistent between both chrome and opera.

Comment: Still outdated and still does not work. Any Updates?