# Google Chrome new devtools window opens on page refresh

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools

#### Version details

- Google Chrome build 59.0.3071.115 (64 bit)
- Mac OS X 10.12.5
- Angular 4.3.0

#### Problem

Every time I refresh the page of my Angular project in Chrome with the devtools open in the sidebar, a blank devtools window opens. This window doesn't seem to be connected at all to the current page. This *only* happens with the Angular project, so I suspect it's an issue related to it.

I've tried the solutions described in this thread: ["Drawer" panel keeps showing up on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159780/drawer-panel-keeps-showing-up-on-refresh) to no success.

#### Images

The blank console opened on refresh (note how there's no dock side in the menu). Note the strange URL.

[image: The blank console]

Here's what the regular console looks like for reference (this one is attached to the webpage).

[image]

---

Thanks in advance for any help. Let me know if there's any other information I can provide that would be helpful. I would prefer not to provide the whole project I'm working on and I unfortunately don't have a minimally working example. If that means that my issue can't be resolved, then I might just deal with it and hope it goes away.

Comment: In the side context menu there is an option setting which has Restore defaults and reload button. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Vega yes, at least twice. It's also not displaying this behavior outside of my Angular project, which leads me to believe it's an issue there.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, look for an existing report on https://crbug.com or submit a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest you:

- Clear your cache and other browser data;
- Try using Incognito Mode;
- Reset your Chrome settings;
- Run Chrome Cleanup Tool, to remove software that may cause Chrome to experience issues.

Comment: I finally got back to my computer and I tried resetting the settings after I found that my issue was gone in Incognito Mode. I've no clue what was causing these issues, but at least it's gone now and I have a fix for it were it to happen in the future. Thanks.